# Integrating an Angular SPA in a webpage - Request for suggestion

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe, single-page-application

I have a CMS based website where I need to add a standalone AngularJS based app. Given the single minified JS for the app is 13Mbs.

**The options that I see are:**

**A.)** EMBED the app directly in a webpage, we can add a `SECTION`/`DIV` on a webpage and let the script render the app in that tag. With this approach, my concerns are the additional `HTTP request` and the obvious 13Mbs of additional data.

**B.)** The other way is to add this app using an `iframe` and pass the URL, this is the straightforward way. I will not have to retouch the CSS as well. This approach helps in eliminating the above concerns. But I will have to write additional manage the height of `iframe` to make sure the app looks like a part of the page itself.

**Your SUGGESTION, please.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ask the team to reduce the file size of your javascript or break it into multiple pieces based on nature of your application.
2. If the libraries inside the application ( JS/CSS) are non conflicting - (which is not the usual case) opt for embeding, because it would give a seamless integration.
3. If you want to make sure your pages are safe and the application is from third party where you dont have control, put that in an iframe. Ask the third party to talk to your javascript by post messaging, so that you can resize it as and when required. Refer (https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/cross-domain-iframe-parent-communication-403912fff692)